# how to avoid jquery toggle when the slide is active?

Tags: jquery

I need to avoid the jquery toggle for the active slide.suppose if i click on open slide,no actions should not be performed.

this is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".review-title").click(function(){
      jQuery(".review-details").slideUp();
      jQuery(this).next(".review-details").slideToggle("slow");
      jquery(this).toggleClass("active");return false;
    });
});
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the active class is added to the element using [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".review-title").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        //if the item has the class active don't do anything
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $(".review-details").slideUp();
            $this.next(".review-details").slideToggle("slow");
            $this.addClass("active");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It is working one time only.For the second time the slides are not opening.If im clicking on the opened slide,the slide close and then open.I need to avoid that

Comment: @GengaShree can you share the html sample

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your html code so i can't understand your problem. But I think this code may help you

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(".review-title").click(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
                jQuery(".review-details").slideUp();
                jQuery(this).next(".review-details").slideToggle("slow");
                jquery(this).toggleClass("active");
                return false;
            }


        });
    });
```